# Coldfusion Upload of CSV returns mime-type error with mime-type 'text/plain'

Tags: coldfusion, mime-types, coldfusion-10, cffile

I'm having trouble with ColdFusion 10. Code *has* been working, I'm not sure what changed where - the code itself hasn't changed in months in this area.

I have a cffile that looks like this:

```
<cffile action="upload" filefield="fileLocation" 
    destination="#destination#" 
    nameConflict="Overwrite" 
    accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,text/csv" 
    result="upload">
```

I have a .csv file I'm uploading. The error I get is this (cfcatch.message and then cfcatch.detail):

```
The MIME type or the Extension of the uploaded file text/plain was 
not accepted by the server. 

Only files of type application/vnd.ms-excel,text/csv can be uploaded. 
Verify that you are uploading a file of the appropriate type.
```

In Firebug, the Post portion of the Net entry for this looks like this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileLocation"; filename="myfilename.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
```

If I take away the accept="" attribute and then do a cfdump of #upload#, I get:

```
CONTENTSUBTYPE  vnd.ms-excel
CONTENTTYPE     application
```

Or, in other words, CF is *receiving* the application/vnd.ms-excel that Firefox is sending. And yet. The mime-type it is deriving is text/plain.

I've checked the file - it's in a CSV format, the same one that has been uploaded just fine before. I've renamed the file to .txt and then back to .csv, just in case somehow it was an extension-related issue. Same error. I've verified that I don't have the file open.

My user is using our production server to try this. I am using our development server. So whatever it is, it's not specific to a single server.

Does anyone understand why it's coming up with text/plain? I would vaguely understand it if it was getting application/octet-stream; text/plain is just...confusing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran up against the same thing when our CF9 servers were upgraded to CF11. What I ended up doing was to add `text/plain` as an allowed MIME type and then add a check that the extension was `csv`.

Comment: You are better off using more secure alternatives - instead of "accept" - anyway. Mime types can be easily spoofed See [Tips for Secure File Uploads with ColdFusion](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm). +1 for a well phrased, and researched, question.

Comment: This seems new in CF 10 to me Leigh. I think that rather than rely on the browser POST disposition info CF10 and 11 are looking at the actual file header for information. A csv file might naturally report itself as text/plain eh?

Comment: We're doing more checks than just the mime-type, definitely. It's a convenience thing more than anything else.

I ended up just adding text/plain - I don't want to take the mime-type check off because it does let us give a nice clean error message about the format if it's definitively not being sent the way we want it. Then our other checks take effect to make sure it's the particular columns we're expecting in it. Thanks for the help, folks!

Comment: @Mark - I could see it reporting "text/plain", just not "application/vnd.ms-excel" as stated above ;-) *RE: CF10 and 11 are looking at the actual file header* Oh, yes. I forgot that started in CF10. Leanne - Mark might be on to something. Take a look the examples under [modifications to "accept"](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cffile). For grins, what happens if you temporarily change the original upload code to use `strict="false"`? If it works, then Mark's probably right that the change in "accept" behavior is why it did not work.

Comment: Bingo, Leigh, that's it. I had read that and it said that the default value of strict is false, so I didn't think it applied! Shows you what I know... I *would* think that if the first bytes identify it as text, and the extension is csv, that CF should generate it as text/csv, not text/plain, but what do I know...

Comment: Well, I do not think the logic is *that* advanced ;-) But looking at the docs again, it sounds like the checks performed depend on what filters you use in the "accept" value. Supposedly "accept" allows both mime type and file extensions. Since you are only using mime types, CF does not look at the file extension at all. The "strict" setting does sound like an improvement over the old method. So you might want to play around with the settings to see if you can find a secure combination that works in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Put an attribute of strict="false" into the `<cffile>` tag.

Even if the default is presumed to be false, put the strict in anyway rather than relying on the default.

Also review this for other CF10 changes to cffile: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cffile